# Calling a sub based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have three different Subs available in a VBA and want to call those Subs from an unique Sub using button.
Either of the sub should be called based on the condition, but no sub is getting called!

```
Sub rush_hour()
    If Range("B2").Value = "Greater Than" Then
        Call call_rus_greater
    ElseIf Range("B2").Value = "Less Than" Then
        Call call_rus_less
    ElseIf Range("B2").Value = "Equals" Then
        Call call_rus_equals
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be because there might be something else in Cell B2. What is in B2? Also share one of your subs that's been called. It is unlikely to figure out what the problem is with the provided information so far.

Comment: B2 is a dropdown which contains "Greater Than", "Less Than " and "Equals"

Comment: Could you make it a little slicker and have on function with arguments, so `call_rus(enmAction as enmGreaterThanLessThanEnum)` using enumerations for the >,< and =.  Google `Enumerations` and `function arguments`.  Or you could skip enums and just use a string, so `call_rus(worksheets("sheet").range("b2").value)`  Then your logic will be in the function.

Comment: @Peh, people also assumed the problem is "not fully qualifying ranges" while avoiding this assumption ^^

Comment: @Tehscript sorry, I didn't get it. What did you try to tell me with your comment?

Comment: @Peh, sorry my bad, it is not my main language. When you commented not to assume the worksheet for ranges, everyone assumed that this is the problem, and too many answers, comments, upvotes (including me) popped in 5 mins. However OP did not comment that this is true. Maybe the called sub is the problematic part here. So while trying to advise not to assume anything, we assumed all of these ^^

Comment: @Tehscript The problem here is everyone assumes something because the OP didn't ask a good question and provided insufficient information to give an *exact* answer. Therefore I threw this comment in because he should qualify his ranges anyway, even if this appears not to be the main issue here. You must start excluding some issues if there is more than one possible issue and this code *obviously has* more than one possible issue.

Answer (score 3):

The capitalisation in the dropdown is probably different from what you have in your code. It is also possible that there is a space somewhere in the dropdown where there should be none, or that the sheet on which your Range("B2") is specified isn't the active sheet at the time of calling the sub. All of these possibilities are eliminated in the code below.

```
Sub rush_hour()

    Select Case Trim(LCase(ActiveSheet.Range("B2").value))
        Case "greater than"
            call_rus_greater
        Case "less than"
            call_rus_less
        Case "equals"
            call_rus_equals
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Unexpected value in cell B2"
    End Select
End Sub
```